# How to fix 'media button receiver could not be found' exception

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediasession

I'm building media player, and want to handle action from notification like "play", "pause". 
In my activity I registerd `MediaButtonReceiver`

```
registerReceiver(MediaButtonReceiver(), IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON))
```

and created media notification with

```
val builder: NotificationCompat.Builder = MediaStyleHelper.from(this, mediaSession!!)
builder.addAction(
                NotificationCompat.Action(
                        android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous,
                        "Previous",
                        MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)
                )
        )
```

but when I press action buttons on my media notification, nothing happens.
And when I add these actions, executing

```
MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)
```

prints to console a warning

"W/MediaButtonReceiver: A unique media button receiver could not be found in the given context, so couldn't build a pending intent."

But why is it not registered if I have registered it programmatically?

Answer (score 16):

Before you can use `MediaButtonReceiver` functions, you need to add it to the manifest [as described in the docs:](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver)

```
<receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

If you aren't using the AndroidX libraries yet, you need to use the old class name: `android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver`

Answer (score -1):

use in your gradle properties
android.enableJetifier=true